# Openshift secret in Spring Boot bootstrap.yml

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, spring-config

This how my bootstrap.yml looks like.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://xxxx.com
      username: ****
      password: ****
    vault:
      host: vault-server
      port: 8200
      scheme: http
      authentication: token
      token: ${VAULT_ROOT_TOKEN}
  application:
    name: service-name
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

**Application is starting when I configure secret as a ENV variable in Deployment Config** – OSE, as below.

```
   name: VAULT_ROOT_TOKEN
   value: *********
```

But **Configuring secret as a ENV variable and fetching the value from OSE secret is not working**.

```
name: VAULT_ROOT_TOKEN
     valueFrom: 
       secretKeyRef:
         name: vault-token
         key: roottoken
```

Error that I am getting is

```
org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 400 secret/service-name/default: 400 Bad Request: missing required Host header
```

Surprise in this scenario, E**NV variable is working within the container/POD but somehow it is not able to fetch during the bootstrap procedure**.

```
env | grep TOKEN
VAULT_ROOT_TOKEN=********
```

My secret configuration in OSE

```
oc describe secret vault-token
Name:       vault-token
Namespace:  ****
Labels:     <none>
Annotations:    <none>

Type:   Opaque

Data
====
roottoken:  37 bytes
```

**What is missing in my deployment-config or secrets in OSE**? How to configure to fetch secret as ENV variable and inject in the bootstrap.yml file?

NOTE : I can't move Vault configuration out of bootstrap.yml.

Openshift Enterprise info:

```
Version:
OpenShift Master:v3.2.1.31
Kubernetes Master:v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to achieve this. This is what I have done

Provide the token as an arugument:

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar -Dspring.cloud.vault.token=${SPRING_CLOUD_VAULT_TOKEN} service-name.jar
```

This is how my configuration looks like:

Deployment Config:

```
- name: SPRING_CLOUD_VAULT_TOKEN
             valueFrom:
               secretKeyRef:
                 name: vault-token
                 key: roottoken
```

Bootstrap file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://xxxx.com
      username: ****
      password: ****
    vault:
      host: vault-server
      port: 8200
      scheme: http
      authentication: token
      token: ${SPRING_CLOUD_VAULT_TOKEN}
  application:
    name: service-name
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Thanks for my colleagues who has provided the inputs.